# Find specific occurrence and parse it into an array.

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, screen-scraping

I have a bunch of disorganized information in a var, and I want to:

1. Loop over the info and extract all the numbers that are preceded with a currency symbol $, or the word Price.
2. Input all these occurrences into an array

So far I have found a way to find occurrence of the dollar sign, but I have no idea on the rest of the steps I have to take.

```
var str = "My father/taughtme$500ho<div>wtoPrice:700throwabaseball$30";
var getCount=function(str){
    return (str.match(/$/g) || []).length;
};
alert(getCount(str));
```

Appreciate any help, and sorry if I am not detailed enough.

Comment: please supply the result of your example. price is written with `:`. should it be included as well?

Comment: Hi Nina, the result of my example returns the number of occurrences of the symbol, perhaps a loop that finds numbers that precede with "$" is a better idea but I don't really know how to go about implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `.match` and a regular expression.

```js
var data = "My father/taughtme$500ho<div>wtoPrice:700throwabaseball$30";

var prices = (data.match(/[\$|price:]\d+/gi) || []).map(function(m) {
  //Convert each match to a number
  return +m.substring(1);
});

document.write(prices);
console.log(prices);
```

The expression `/[\$|price:]\d+/gi` matches all numbers that start with `$` or `price:`, in any case.  Then, use `map` to convert each match to a number, and chop off the `:` or `$`.

Comment: That is brilliantly simple, thank you so much Scott!

Comment: Bear in mind that this will produce an error in the event that `match()` finds no matches; meaning in that case `map()` will be applied to `null`. Also, @jcdenton, if this answer correctly solved your problem please consider accepting it as the correct answer (by checking the greyed-out check mark (✔) character below the score).

Comment: @DavidThomas Good point, I've updated the answer to account for this.  Thank you!